# NeoVim Telescope (enable hidden files mapping)

Tags: lua, neovim, telescope

I want to create a mapping for Ctrl+H in insert mode to show all hidden files, but unfortunately, this configuration doesn't work.

```
require('telescope').setup {
  defaults = {
    mappings = {
      i = {
        ['<C-u>'] = false,
        ['<C-d>'] = false,
--        ['<C-h>'] = require("telescope.builtin").find_files({hidden=true, layout_config={prompt_position="top"}}),
      },
    },
  },
}
```